# how to create link in django admin to custom django admin url?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

how to create link  in django admin to custom django admin url i have 2 apps in django admin and i want to link from app1 to custom url in app 2

admin.py APP1

```
class APP1Admin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('xx','request_me')

    def request_me(self,obj):

       reverse_path = reverse("admin: APP2_TargetLink",args=(obj.pk,)) # My Problem is  How to link to func APP2 target link

       return '<a href="%s"> link </a>'%(reverse_path)

    request_me.allow_tags =True
```

admin.py APP2

```
class APP2Admin(ModelAdmin):

   def get_urls(self):
       urls = super(APP2Admin, self).get_urls()
       my_urls = [
       url(r'(\d*)/target_link/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.target_link_view),name="TargetLink"),
    ]
      return my_urls + urls

    def target_link_view(self,request,id):
       ...
       return TemplateResponse(request, template, context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `name="TargetLink"` when you define the URL pattern, therefore you can reverse the URL with

```
reverse("admin:TargetLink",args=(obj.pk,))
```

If you want `app2` to be in the URL pattern name you have to include it yourself, for example:

```
   url(r'(\d*)/target_link/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.target_link_view),name="app2_TargetLink"),
```

Then reverse it with:

```
reverse("admin:app2_TargetLink",args=(obj.pk,))
```

Comment: i tried your solution but i have a error:

Reverse for 'app2_TargetLink' not found. 'app2_TargetLink' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: Does your target link view definitely work? Does my first suggestion work?

Comment: Try changing the regex to `r'^(\d+)/target_link/$'`.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any other suggestions. I can't spot the problem in your code. Using made-up names like `app1` and `app2` makes it even trickier.

Comment: tanks again bro :) this app1 and app 2 is sample name